# How can I restrict users to retrieve only their data from Cloud Firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm building an app with Kotlin. In the app, the user can sign up and log in. After the user log in, the user adds some text and pictures, and these data is successfully added to the firebase cloud store and displayed in the app as a list. However, this list can be accessed by anyone registered on the app.

What I want to do is how users can only see their own data. So I don't want users to see each other's data. I just want every user to see their own added data. I think that I need to change Cloud Firestore rules. How do I set permission to specific document?

I'm new to this field, Thank you !

My firebase Cloud Store rules;

```
 rules_version = '2';
    service cloud.firestore {
      match /databases/{database}/documents {
       match/Notes/{noteId}{
       allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null ;
       
            }
        }
    }
```

[this is my firebase cloud store screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWqdB.png)

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect? Do you have any errors?

Comment: I do not have any errors. I try to make a note app to practice. The issue is that users see notes which the other users cretaed. I try to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

it's done by settings up the rules. You can read more here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security#section-overview

Comment: Links to documentation is great but the best answers provide some context around what it being linked. In this case the user is asking for a rule that would enable a user to only ready their own data.  Can you suggest how that rule would look? Also, that's the wrong link for the rules asked about in the question.